# What is the difference between transaction and message?

Tags: transactions, terminology, internal-transactions

What is the definition of a transaction and a message in Ethereum?
How are they different?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [Yellow Paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper):

> **Transaction**: A piece of data, signed by an External Actor. It
>   represents either a Message or a new Autonomous Object. Transactions
>   are recorded into each block of the blockchain.

This means that a transaction represents either a Message or a new contract.

> **Message**: Data (as a set of bytes) and Value (specified as Ether) that is passed between two Accounts, either through the deterministic
>   operation of an Autonomous Object or the cryptographically secure
>   signature of the Transaction

This means that a Message is the data and amount of Ether that is passed between two accounts.  A message is created by contracts interacting with each other, or by a transaction.  (In practice the Ether is specified in units of Wei.)

Transactions are explicitly on the blockchain, and messages are "internal", see [example](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6476/42).

For a related question with more practical help than just terminology, see
[What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call)