# Internal Transaction?

Tags: transactions

Hi im new on the blockchain, so i have a specific question :
I did a withdraw from EtherDelta and they send me an "internal transaction", so i cant see the new balance on my wallet..
Someone can explain me where are my ether ? 
Why they cant do normal transaction ?
Thanks for the answer

Tx : https://etherscan.io/tx/0xce5d12239074fc77229f869cc558fe542a29714f15e535eb13d3b70efecf9d19

Answer (score 0):

[Normal transactions VS. Internal transactions in etherscan](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6429/normal-transactions-vs-internal-transactions-in-etherscan)

There is no difference in terms of sending/receiving Ether for "normal" vs. "internal" transactions.  Other than an "internal" transaction just means that the value transfer resulted from the execution of a contract function, rather than an explicit and outright Ether transfer.