# Ethereum Internal transactions how to work with it?

Tags: transactions, internal-transactions

I've covered a bunch of forums and I do not understand what Internal Transactions is in etherscan. I have been transferred to the transaction and it is in Internal Transactions. And I do not see her in my balance. How do I bring them to the main wallet, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internal transactions aren't actual transactions on the blockchain and therefore aren't included directly in the blockchain. Internal transactions are value transfers initiated by a contract or when a contract simply makes a call to another contract. The result of the value transfer or contract call isn't stored on the blockchain and therefore you cannot return the result of the internal transaction from the blockchain.

Etherscan obtains the results of these transactions by running a modified node that records all the value transfers by looking at the actual transaction that resulted in the change, and then stores the effects of the transaction separately as an 'internal transaction'. Currently there is not any way to imitate this process simply using the web3 API.

These related questions provide more information:

[Normal transactions VS. Internal transactions in etherscan](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6429/normal-transactions-vs-internal-transactions-in-etherscan)

[How to get contract internal transactions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/how-to-get-contract-internal-transactions)

Comment: So it is possible to move ether from one account to another without it ever being registered on the blockchain?