# ETC - Negative Balance

Tags: ethereum-classic, balances

So playing around with ETC and wondering how in the world this address doesn't have a negative balance?

https://gastracker.io/addr/0x6f1f8a70e2257354e81c306f130f7976dead8e8b

First transactions are outputs and it didn't seem to have any transactions pre fork on ETH.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x6f1f8a70e2257354e81c306f130f7976dead8e8b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internal transactions.

You'll have to use a more comprehensive block explorer to see them though: https://blockscout.com/etc/mainnet/address/0x6f1f8a70e2257354e81c306f130f7976dead8e8b/internal_transactions

(Background: [Normal transactions VS. Internal transactions in etherscan](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6429/normal-transactions-vs-internal-transactions-in-etherscan))

Comment: Ahh ok, I was aware of internal vs normal but thought gastracker was displaying both! Thanks @Richard Horrocks

As a follow up I was trying to utilize geth_getAddressTransactions call using geth_getAddressTransactions('0x6f1f8a70e2257354e81c306f130f7976dead8e8b', 0, 9143764, 'tf', 'sc', -1, -1, false)

I'm guessing that it also doesn't return the internal transactions based on the output....

Comment: Correct - it won't show them. I think EtherScan gets the details of internal transactions by basically replaying everything in an instantiation of the EVM and noting what happens (e.g. by looking for CALL opcodes and their cousins).