# Ether withdrawal shown as "internal" transaction

Tags: ether, wallets, pending-transactions, internal-transactions, recovery

I requested a withdrawal of 490usd of eth to this address :
0x4fc9bbcf8fd82221ffa0508cac3e094cf7123de7

from bitstamp. The transaction showed "finished" in bitstamp but I never received the money! Can someone tell me why have I not received the money yet? It shows as internal transaction.

Comment: The money was already accredited to that address on block 11,329,307, it doesn't matter if it is internal transaction. If the wallet doesn't allow to spend it, then the wallet is wrong and you should use a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have the money:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x4fc9bbcf8fd82221ffa0508cac3e094cf7123de7

Balance:
0.79896513 Ether

Here is the internal transaction:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x637c8159388988ce27315d25d8b56a0bc6ee8f9812d8b58c19316536ccb0ab93

Basically, the reason for the internal transaction is that Bitstamp had funds in a contract, the "To", and they used the "From" account to tell the contract to send you your money.

Related: [Normal transactions VS. Internal transactions in etherscan](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6429/normal-transactions-vs-internal-transactions-in-etherscan)

Comment: I  had to ask my wallet to transfer me the funds and they did so, thank you