# Which type of transaction comes under internal transaction on etherscan

Tags: transactions, etherscan, internal-transactions

Etherscan contract details interface shows internal transaction which type of transactions comes under it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A contract address hosts a smart contract, which is a set of code stored on the blockchain that runs when a transaction with associated input data (contract interaction) is made to it. [Source](https://info.etherscan.com/what-is-an-ethereum-address/).

---

> **Internal transactions, despite the name** (which isn't part of the yellowpaper; it's a convention people have settled on) **aren't actual
> transactions**, and aren't included directly in the blockchain;
> **they're value transfers that were initiated by executing a contract**.

As such, they're not stored explicitly anywhere: they're the effects of running the transaction in question on the blockchain state. Blockchain explorers like etherscan obtain them by running a modified node with an instrumented EVM, which record all the value transfers that took place as part of transaction execution, storing them separately. For more info, take a look at [this](https://coinmarketcap.com/alexandria/glossary/internal-transaction), [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/how-to-get-contract-internal-transactions) and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6429/normal-transactions-vs-internal-transactions-in-etherscan).

---

To understand this, check out the following **example**:

The EOA address A wants to send some ERC-20 tokens to the EOA address C. To do this, the EOA address A should make a transfer transaction to the ERC-20 Contract address B, with these parameters:

```
tx_obj = {
            'from'      : EOA_address_A,
            'to'        : ERC_20_Contract_address_B,
            'value'     : 0,
            'data'      : data,
            'gas'       : estimated_gas,
            'gasPrice'  : web3.eth.gas_price,
            'nonce'     : web3.eth.get_transaction_count(EOA_address_A),
            'chainId'   : web3.eth.chain_id
            }
```

wherein

```
estimated_gas = self.w3.eth.estimate_gas({
            'from'      : EOA_address_A,
            'to'        : ERC_20_Contract_address_B,
            'value'     : 0,
            'data'      : data,
            'nonce'     : web3.eth.get_transaction_count(EOA_address_A),
            'chainId'   : web3.eth.chain_id
            })
```

and

```
data = contract_token.encodeABI(fn_name="transfer", args=[EOA_address_C, to_wei(amount, 'ether')])
```

wherein

```
contract_token = web3.eth.contract(address=ERC_20_Contract_address_B, abi=ERC_20_Contract_address_B_abi)
```

In this example, the EVM recognizes tx_obj as transaction parameters : 0 amount from EOA_address_A to ERC_20_Contract_address_B with "data" as data. This is called a transaction.

The so called Internal transaction is the consequence of this transaction. i.e., with this transaction made, by triggering the transfer function in the ERC_20_Contract_address_B and passing the "data" provided by this transaction, ERC_20_Contract_address_B's transfer function will be run and tokens will be transferred to EOA_address_C.

Because of this fact that running this function won't change the blockchain state (despite the main transaction), the EVM won't recognize this as a transaction and people conventionally call this an internall transaction. However, blockchain explorers like etherscan obtain them by running a modified node with an instrumented EVM, which record all the value transfers that took place as part of transaction execution, storing them separately.

Comment: "Because of this fact that running this function won't change the blockchain state (despite the main transaction)". No, it does change the blockchain state, the storage of ERC_20_Contract_address_B is changed.

Answer (score 0):

- [These are transfers that occur where the `fromAddress` is an internal (smart contract) address](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/guides/using-notify#:%7E:text=These%20are%20transfers%20that%20occur%20where%20the%20fromAddress%20is%20an%20internal%20(smart%20contract)%20address)
- [check this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6429/normal-transactions-vs-internal-transactions-in-etherscan)